# Error: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists. How fix it?

Tags: spring, hibernate, many-to-one

I'm doing with Hibernate many to one for my project. When i browser "http://localhost:8080/subject/list" for display list Subject, but then i see this error:

> INFO: HHH000327: Error performing load command :
>   org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundExc eption: No row with the given
>   identifier exists: [edu.java.spring.model.Student# 2101]

Here file Student.java

```
@XmlRootElement(name="item")
@Entity
@Table(name = "student",uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames="id")})
public class Student {
    // @NotBlank
    // @Size(min=2,max=100,message ="Age value is invalid")
    private String name;

    private int id;
    // @Range(min=1,max=150)
    private int age;

    @XmlAttribute
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @XmlElement
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
```

Here file Subject.java

```
public class Subject {
//  @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
//  @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int id;
    public String title;
    public Student student;
    public int score;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
//  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
//  @Column(name = "student", nullable = false)
    public Student getStudent() {
        return student;
    }
    public void setStudent(Student student) {
        this.student = student;
    }
//  @Column(name = "score", nullable = false)
    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    public void setScore(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

}
```

Here file Subject.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="edu.java.spring.model.Subject" table="subject">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class contains the subject detail
        </meta>
        <id name = "id" type = "int" column="id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="title" column="title" type="string"/>
        <many-to-one name="student" column="student"
            class="edu.java.spring.model.Student" not-null="true" lazy="false"/>
        <property name="score" column="score" type="int"/>



    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here file SubjectController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="subject/list",method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listSubjects(){

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("SubjectList");

        model.addObject("subjects", subjectDao.listSubject());
//      System.out.println("anh yeu em");
        return model;
```

Comment: Are you missing referential integrity? Does your `subject` table contain rows where `studentId` has a value but that value doesn't exist in the `id` column of the `student` table? If there are rows like that, delete them (they're corrupt), add referential integrity (foreign key from `subject.studentid` to `student.id`), and try again.

Comment: @PaulHicks, thank you very much, i have fixed error